# How do you format the tickLabel color of Victory Charts VictoryAxis?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, victory-charts

```js
<VictoryAxis
  tickFormat={tickFormat}
  tickValues={tickValues}
  style={{
    tickLabels: {color: 'white'}, //  not working
  }}
/>
```

How do I change the tickLabel color?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for `fill` instead of `color`:

```
// ...
style={{
   tickLabels: {fill: 'white'}, 
}}
// ...
```

Comment: That was it. Thanks. 
How do you figure out all the styles available for VictoryCharts? The docs aren't super helpful in this area.

Comment: The React Native implementation of Victory Charts didn't give me much info, but the React implementation documentation goes into a lot more depth. I saw `fill` being used a lot on different elements, so I tried it out for `VictoryAxis`. This faq page in the documentation gives a nice overview I think of style related things you can do https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/docs/faq/#styles.